# Disable application.hbs for a single route in Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js

Simply, the web app needs to use the application.hbs template 99% of the time but for a single route, I would like to disable it and render only the route template.

Like 'Layout=null;' in asp.net

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest answer is that you need to nest all the routes that share a layout under a common parent route, since you can't remove the application template. This can be done in a couple different ways, depending on the goal.

If they all share a URL segment, you can put then under a common parent:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('pretty-layout', function() {
    this.route('page-1'); // http://localhost:4200/pretty-layout/page-1
    this.route('page-2'); // http://localhost:4200/pretty-layout/page-2
  });
});
```

You can override the top-level index route. You'll likely need to move the current `application.index` to `application.index.index`:

```
 Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('page-1'); // http://localhost:4200/page-1
    this.route('page-2'); // http://localhost:4200/page-2
  });
});
```